# Как разделить число на разряды и вывести палиндром этого числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
number = int(input("Enter any number: "))

print("Palindrome : ")

while number > 0 :

    digit = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    print(digit)
```

Попробовал так, но вывод совсем непонятный

Comment: `input()[::-1]` или вам надо именно через цикл?

Comment: `print("Palindrome : ", end="") ... print(digit, end="")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще-то `input()[::-1]`, но если по заданию нужен цикл, можно так

```
number = int(input("Enter any number: "))

print("Palindrome : ")  
while number > 0 :
    number, digit = divmod(number,10);
    print(digit, end='')
```